# Trying to create model for json

Tags: c#, json

How to create model for this json? I can't understand how to add dictinary to this string array.

```
{
  "ts": 1652718271,
  "updates": [
    [
      4,
      508976,
      33,
      466697301,
      1551996353,
      "Цацу",
      {
        "title": " ... ",
        "type": "photo"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, try adding more detail to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this model you can deserialize using Newtonsoft.Json

```
class Serial 
{
    public string ts { get; set; }
    public object [][] updates { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to handle JSON arrays of varied types. One way is to define a class with nullable fields of the types you may encounter in the array. For example,

```
public class Model
{
    public int TS;
    public Update[][] Updates;
}

public class Update
{
    public int? Number;
    public string Word;
    public ModelDictionary Dictionary;
}

public class ModelDictionary
{
    public string Title;
    public string Type;
}
```

Then you could access each `Update` with something like

```
if (Number != null) { ... }
else if (Word != null) { ... }
else if (Dictionary != null) { ... }
```

Also, https://app.quicktype.io/ is always a great resource for generating C# models from JSON objects.